# How to uninstall Linux, from a dual-booting Windows 10 PC?

Tags: linux, boot, partition, uninstall

Suppose I installed some type of Linux on a Windows PC, to achieve a dual-boot system.  Then, what steps do I need to un-do the installation of Linux?

This question applies to:

- Standard EFI boot, as used on any known PC sold with a Windows 10 logo.  (And equally on Windows 8 :-).
- Standard 64-bit EFI.  (Some Windows PCs use 32-bit EFI, but it is not as widely supported by the different distributions of Linux, or Linux-based boot disks).
- The Linux install of your choice.  Provided that you list steps for removing a swap partition and a filesystem partition.
- The Windows install is still bootable :-).

---

(Inspired by [What should I be careful about when dual booting windows and a linux distro?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458326/what-should-i-be-careful-about-when-dual-booting-windows-and-a-linux-distro))

Answer (score 2):

## THESE STEPS HAVE NOT BEEN TESTED OR CONFIRMED. OTHER USERS SUGGEST THAT WINDOWS BECOMES UNSTABLE.

---

### 1. Find/create a suitable Linux live USB, which lets you run GParted.

Of course it also needs to work on your hardware and support your main disk drive :).  There are two options that I can currently recommend:

You may use Ubuntu Live which included GParted already.  You may write Ubuntu Live to a USB, by running the Ubuntu "Startup Disk Creator" from Windows or from Ubuntu.

Usually your current Linux has a live USB version.  Even if it does not include GParted to start with, you can usually install GParted on the running system once you have booted it.  E.g. if you use Fedora Workstation, you might like to use the Fedora Workstations USB that you installed from.

### 2. Boot the Linux live USB - but make sure Windows is not hibernated.

If Windows is hibernated, you won't be able to resize the Windows partition back to its full original size.  *Windows 10 uses hibernation by default when you click "shut down", because of a feature called "Fast boot"*.

The good news is, you managed to do this once already, when you installed Linux :).  If you're not certain, all you need to do is boot Windows, and then reboot into the Linux live USB.

Full instructions to boot from Windows into a live USB on *any* Windows 10 system are available [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21756-boot-usb-drive-windows-10-pc.html).

### 3. View disk partitions.

Open a Terminal window, and run `sudo fdisk -l` (or `su` and then `fdisk -l`).  This will show us all the disk partitions, their size, and what type they are labelled as.  (If you used LVM e.g. because of Fedora Linux, this may also list each LVM Logical Volumes (LV), as "Disk /dev/mapper/...").

You could also open GParted at this point, to see a graphical view.

### 4. Identify the disk partitions.

Identify the EFI System Partition, then which partitions you want to keep and which partitions to delete.  You should be able to identify every partition.

The partitions you want to keep, which should be in this order:

- 1. EFI system partition (ESP).
- 2. Windows reserved partition (128 megabytes or so).
- 3. Windows (NTFS filesystem).
- At the end of the drive, optionally: a Windows recovery partition.

The partitions you want to delete:

- All Linux filesystems.
- Linux swap partitions.
- And/or if you used LVM, the Linux Physical Volumes (PVs).
- And/or if you used software RAID, the Linux RAID partitions.

(I'm assuming Linux was installed to the same ESP that Windows uses.  This was the default [for Fedora Linux 25](http://linuxbsdos.com/2016/12/01/dual-boot-fedora-25-windows-10-on-a-computer-with-uefi-firmware/), and also for Ubuntu.  Otherwise, you could adapt the next step to double-check the contents of both ESPs, and hence which one you want to delete).

### 6. Remove the EFI boot menu entry for Linux.  And remove the Linux files from the ESP.

Follow these instructions in the terminal: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi/63613#63613

After removing the EFI boot entry, it will also be removed from the EFI `BootOrder`.  "Windows Boot Manager" will become the first and default entry in `BootOrder`.

### 7. Now open the graphical app GParted.

To find GParted on Ubuntu (and many others), hit the Windows key and start typing "gparted".

### 8. Use GParted to delete the Linux partitions.

### 9. Use GParted to resize the Windows partition, reclaiming the space that Linux took up.

Comment: Resizing windows partitions with gparted is a recipe for disaster. Windows see's the new partition table as false and you will get BSOD'd. I have first hand experience with this. Can I suggest you change #9 to something like "reboot the laptop into windows and then use diskmgt to resize the windows partition to fill the empty space" Much safer and I'll +1 that

Comment: @bashCypher thanks for your experience! I don't have any experience with diskmgt (diskmgr?), and I've used Linux installers which *shrink* Windows, AFAIK with the same underlying code base as GParted.  For now I think the best I can do is slap a "not tested, do not use" warning on this.  Please edit the warning if I have mis-phrased what you mean.